# Remote Database Connection Setup in Netbeans

Tags: postgresql, netbeans-7, remote-connection

I'm totally junior in this area :)

I have JAVA version 7 on my PC.
[image]

I want to connect my PostgreSQL database to NetBeans.
Based on my search I found that I should get JDBC driver. so I downloaded `JDBC41 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.3-1100` jar files [from here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html).

then based on what I found for [connection remote Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081579/513413), did similar changes to connect to my PostgreSQL database.
[image]

As you can see in the image, connection couldn't established. 
Based on what my [host says](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/89), I added my IP address to "Remote PostgreSQL Database Access" page of my host.

I'm not sure my host name is correct. I used Dedicated IP Address of my site.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My fault was entering wrong user name and pass instead of using user name and password of database :(