# how to connect a mysql database to a project in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to connect mysql database to a project in netbeans. I tried few ways but while running the application i am getting error as

```
u Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I think my way of connecting may be wrong. Give me information regarding that. My localhost is running in 8080 and mysql which i connected is running in 3306 port. Can anyone give exact steps for connecting database to my applicaiton

Comment: example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Comment: Please post your Code.. I think you should check your password what you r passing as a Parameter.

Comment: @TomN my question is regarding connection in netbeans not in normal java program using jdbc drivers.

Comment: then: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect Mysql database with NetBeans then please follow below steps.

> **1**. In the Services window you can right click on the Databases tab and select New Connection.
>
> **2**. Select `MySQL(Connector/J Driver)` from the `drop-down` list. The `driver` file should be listed in the window. If not, you can download the file, then click add and select it from your `hard drive`.
>
> **3**. Finally enter your `database` details such as `servername`, `username` and `password` and click **finish**.

for more detail check [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081307/how-to-connect-netbeans-to-mysql-database)

For PHP check this link [connect it with your PHP application](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Let me know in which language you are trying to connect mysql database?

Comment: I followed the same process but getting same error as before

Comment: have you verified the password of that user from mysql database? and also do that user has permission of localhost?

Comment: after creating database who to linkup with application (without using code)

Comment: by default root user has permission of all databases. Please try to connect your application with root user and use same password which you use to open phpmyadmin. If you have created new database user then give permission to that user. You can find detail in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql